# Connect Qt application to PostgreSQL DB without driver

Tags: qt, postgresql

Subj: is it possible?
If yes:
1) Is it acceptable programming strategy?
2) How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible.

1. No, it's not an acceptable programming strategy.
2. You would use the classes in the QtNetwork Module to handle the communication with the database. You have to know (learn) the protocol and you would need a module to handle the respones of the database. You would need to reimplement most of the Qt psql driver and use or reimplement the PostgreSQL development libraries.

Answer (score 1):

No You cannot connect to any database without proper driver. For PostgreSQL 7.3 and later you should use QPSQL. If you want you can create your own database driver.

Here you can find description of all supported sql drivers for qt and instructions how to create a new one:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html